# Unable to communicate with the chiara channel gateway In Magento connect

Tags: magento

I am trying to submit extension on the Magento but I am getting the error "An error occurred on the saving extension. Unable to communicate with the chiara channel gateway."

I have included the _ (Under score) in My extension key as well but the problem is still same.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same here started on Saturday. I used same name convention as in previous module from previous day and on Friday worked fine.

I googled it and didn't find any relevant results. But now in 2 days 2 relevant topics. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/867116/. That makes me believe it is something wrong on their side.